# The audio stream plays for one millisecond per flask

Tags: python, sockets, flask

I put together one from pieces of different code, and on the client side when I click play I hear a sound for 0.1 second then the button turns off again. and it turns out that in order to hear anything I need to do a bunch of clicks on the play button.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from pydub import AudioSegment
import io
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)


audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3("C:\\Users\\yarchefis\\Desktop\\music\\1.mp3")


def stream_audio():
    CHUNK_SIZE = 1024
    audio_data = io.BytesIO()

    # Конвертация аудиофайла в формат MP3
    audio.export(audio_data, format="mp3")
    audio_data.seek(0)

    while True:
        data = audio_data.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
        if not data:
            break
        socketio.emit('audio-stream', {'audio': data}, namespace='/audio')
        time.sleep(0.1)

# Маршрут Flask
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/audio')
def connect():
    emit('audio-stream', {'audio': 'connected'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.start_background_task(stream_audio)
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Audio Stream</title>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Live Audio Stream</h1>

    <audio controls id="audioPlayer">

        Your browser does not support the audio element.

    </audio>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.4.1/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script>

        var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/audio');



        socket.on('audio-stream', function(data) {

            var audioData = new Blob([data.audio], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });

            var audioElement = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');

            audioElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(audioData);

        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

on the client, when I click on play, I should hear music. from all phones, devices in general, I should hear the same thing, like on the radio